# how to show participants lists who are all joined the video call in opentok

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox

I am working on an iOS application (Swift) in which I have used tokbox SDK for adding video chat into iOS app and now I want to add a button called participants when user clicks on participants button i want to show list of people who are all joined the video call.

can anyone guide how to fetch the participants who joined the video call in opentok ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share some code or links to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the streams property on [OTSession](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTSession.html#//api/name/streams). This will give you a number of streams in the session and the name given to them when they are published. When a subscriber connects the [delegate function](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Protocols/OTSubscriberKitDelegate.html#//api/name/subscriberDidConnectToStream:) allows you to access the stream so you can update whenever that happens. You can check for disconnections via the [disconnect delegate function](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Protocols/OTSubscriberKitDelegate.html#//api/name/subscriberDidDisconnectFromStream:).

Comment: thanks for the reply @abdulajet.I have a doubt regarding the implementation of text chat using opentok sdk. i know using Signaling we can send text and data to other clients in the session. i want to implement text chat in ios app, my doubt is does opentok provide text chat UI also part of opentok SDK?

Comment: We don't provide UI as part of the SDK, we do have a sample objc project with some UI https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples/tree/main/Signaling

Comment: Hi @abdulajet,
Unfortunately, when accessing the session.streams property, the app crashes. 
Could not cast value of type 'OTStream' (0x111300428) to 'OTStream' (0x111300ea0).
Any idea what might happen?